# Rails: How can I know which is the tested model in unit tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a test helper with the following signature, in `test_helper.rb`:

```rb
assert_resolve_mapping(model_name, attrs_ary_to_exclude = [])
```

The first parameter is a string representing the actual model to be asserted, i.e.: User, Customer, Invoice, etc.. The second is an array of attributes.

So in my unit tests I have:

```rb
require 'test_helper'

class CustomerUnitTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  test "should resolve mapping" do
    assert_resolve_mapping("Customer", ["created_at", "updated_at"])
  end
end
```

Since I have to call the helper in various unit tests for various models, is there a way to avoid passing the first parameter, `"Customer"` in this case, knowing which is the model being actually tested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can parse the model name out of the class name.

```
def assert_resolve_mapping(attrs_ary_to_exclude = [])
  model_name = self.class.to_s.sub(/UnitTest\Z/, "")
  ...
end
```